# How do different inner products give different angles?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inner-products

I know that for each inner product $\langle , \rangle_{A}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is an associated positive definite symmetric matrix $A$ so that $\langle x,y \rangle = x^{T}Ay$.  I was wondering if it is possible to find a function relating the angles between $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the dot product, to the angle in another inner product space.

For example a function $f(\theta,A)$, so that if $\theta$ is the dot product between $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f(\theta,A) = \langle x,y \rangle_A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not generally possible to do so.  For example, consider the inner product given by
$$
A = \pmatrix{
2&1&0\\
1&2&0\\
0&0&1
}
$$
Consider $x = (1,0,0)$ and $y = (0,1,0)$.  We find that $\langle x,y \rangle_A = x^TAy = 1$, so that $f(0,A) = 1$.

On the other hand, if $x = (1,0,0)$ and $y = (0,0,1)$, we find that $\langle x,y \rangle = x^TAy = 0$, so that $f(0,A) = 0$.

Comment: Angle are not invariant unless $A$ is orthonormal I think

Comment: @ja72 not quite